# Returning a reference of a struct instead of a copy on C# 3.0?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public interface HaveId
{
    int id { get; }
}

public struct BusinessData : HaveId
{
    // business type data
    public int graphic_asset_id;
    public string name;
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class LookupHelper<T> where T: HaveId
{
    private T[] _list;
    public T[] list
    {
        get { return _list; }
        set { _list = value; _mapToDictionary(); }
    }

    private Dictionary<int, int> idxById = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    public LookupHelper(){}

    private void _mapToDictionary()
    {
        if(idxById.Count > 0) idxById = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        for(var z =0 ; z < list.Length; ++z)
        {
            idxById[list[z].id] = z;
        }
    }

    public bool IsIdExists(int id)
    {
        return idxById.ContainsKey(id);
    }

    public T ById(int id) // is this a reference?
    {
        var idx = idxById[id];
        if (idx >= list.Length) throw new Exception(
                String.Format("Invalid Index: {0} >= {1} on {2}",idx.ToString(),list.Length.ToString(), typeof(T).Name)
            );
        return list[idx];
    } 
}
```

And the test code:

```
LookupHelper<BusinessData> bd = new LookupHelper<BusinessData>();
bd.list = new BusinessData[]
{
    new BusinessData{id = 1, name = "test"},
    new BusinessData{id = 2, name = "test2"},
};

bd.ById(1).name = "foo";
```

This give an error: `"Cannot modify struct member when accessed struct is not classified as a variable"`

How can I change the value of first `BusinessData` and keep the array still allocated on a contiguous memory (array of struct, needed for cache locality)?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot.

Comment: Are you trying to convert C++ code to C#?

Comment: @BlackFrog not really '___') but what i need is to keep the array of struct in contiguous memory (so `array of class` would defeat the purpose), and quick lookup by `id` of the struct, without have to type the content of `ById` methods everytime I need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a simple matter of splitting it up into a few lines. Extract the object to get a copy, modify the copy, then overwrite it in the array:

```
BusinessData bsd = bd.ById(1);
bsd.name = "foo";
bd.SetById(1, bsd);
```

Of course, you'll need to write that `SetById` method to reinsert things into the array:

```
public void SetById(int id, T obj)
{
    Int32 idx = idxById[id];
    list[idx] = obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know C# borrowed something’s from C and Java. But not everything.

In C, you can create a place for `struct` on the stack or the heap. On the heap, I can then pass a pointer around and change the content. Very powerful.

But C# emphasizes ease of memory management via garbage collection. To make it easy, C# has the concept of boxing value types into System.Object. Additional details, can be found on [Microsoft C# Programming Guide on Boxing and unboxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing).

So when you access the value type in your list, you have to explicitly unbox the value. Therefore it’s a copy of the item in the list.  You can do what @Nyerguds suggested.

But to make life easy, why not turn your `BusinessData` into a class?